# Tensorflow cost function placeholder error

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

I have the following code trying to optimize for a linear model with two inputs and three parameters (m_1, m_2 and b). Initially, I had issues with importing the data in a way such that the feed_dict would accept them, which I solved by putting it in a numpy array instead.

Now the optimizer function will run smoothly (and the outputs look roughly like it is optimizing the parameters), but as soon as I try to return the cost with the line at the end:

```
cost_val = sess.run(cost)
```

It returns the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[Node: Placeholder_2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

If I comment out that line alone, everything runs smoothly.

I tried changing the cost function from the more complicated one I was using to something simpler, but the error persists. I know this is probably related to the data input shape(?), but can't figure how the data would work for the optimizer but not the cost function.

```
# reading in data
filename = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file.csv"])
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
key, value = reader.read(filename)
rec_def = [[1], [1], [1]]
input_1, input_2, col3 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=rec_def)

# parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_steps = 300

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

m = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
m2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

y = tf.matmul(x,m) + tf.matmul(x2,m2) + b

# cost function
# cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(1+tf.exp(-y_*y)))
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow((y_-y),2))
# Gradient descent optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# initializing variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(training_steps):

        xs = np.array([[sess.run(input_1)]])
        ys = np.array([[sess.run(input_2)]])
        label = np.array([[sess.run(col3)]])

        feed = {x:xs, x2:ys, y_:label}
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed)
        cost_val = sess.run(cost)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cost` tensor is a function of the placeholder tensors and this requires them to have a value. Since the call to `sess.run(cost)` isn't feeding those placeholders, you're seeing the error. (Putting it another way - what values of `x` and `y_` do you want to compute the cost for?)

So you want to change the line:

```
    cost_val = sess.run(cost)
```

to:

```
    cost_val = sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: *facepalm* So simple and yet I probably would have never figured it out. Thanks a lot!